# Select query, where values have an apostrophe in it

Tags: php, mysqli

I need to use a select query but my code keeps crashing because some of the names have apostrophes in it. I pull all data into a table and half way through it just stops because it hits a apostrophe.

My select Query:

```
$query = mysqli_query($dbh,"select * FROM show_invoice where id_show='$get_id' and status='UNPAID' and scratch = 'Unscratched'and show_deleted != 'Deleted' ORDER BY 'class_no' ASC")
```

There are 3 columns that will possibly contain apostrophes. Any advice on how i can stop it from crashing.

Comment: `$text = 'it\'s' ` This way

Comment: Use addslashes of php

Comment: You are open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. This would also solve the issue you're having

Comment: Read about SQL Injection please.

Comment: Using `addslashes()` is _**NOT even CLOSE**_ to enough to escape input data. Using Prepared Statemants is.

Comment: But you see, asker has been satisfied with my answer.

Comment: @VforVendetta - Just because the OP likes it, it doesn't make it safe from SQL injection attacks. I'm not talking about if it will work for him right now. I'm talking about security. `addslashes()` isn't a secure way to escape input data.

Comment: But asker wants answer he haven't mentioned anything regarding security threats, iff on the point, I am trying to say

Comment: @VforVendetta - Are you serious? You think it's a good idea to recommend insecure ways to do things because the OP, who probably has less experience, didn't specifically ask to prevent a type of attack he might not even know exists? There's _never_ an excuse to _knowingly_ write (or recommend writing) insecure code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132871/discussion-between-v-for-vendetta-and-magnus-eriksson).

Answer (score -1):

You can use [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

So just do

```
$get_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh,$get_id);
```

before running your query.

Note: You should really use prepared statements instead of own queries because of risk of SQL injection attacks.